# ASP.NET MVC 4 and Razor 2: View engine no longer supports xml?

Tags: xml, razor, rss, asp.net-mvc-4

We had a view (.cshtml) which rendered XML for an RSS feed using ASP.NET MVC 3, which worked fine. Now that we have upgraded to ASP.NET MVC 4 with Razor 2 it's generating compile errors, similar to the below.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "item" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?
```

The tags are properly balanced.

Anyone have any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** I've isolated it down the the **link** element within the **item** element within the @foreach (...) { ... } block.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
<item>
    <title>@item.Title</title>
    <link>@item.Link</link>
    <description>@item.Description</description>
    <guid>@item.Guid</guid>
    @if (item.PublishedDateUtc.HasValue)
    {
    <pubDate>@item.PublishedDateUtc.Value.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") GMT</pubDate>
    }  
</item>      
}
```

I fixed it by doing using **@Html.Raw** the below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
<item>
    <title>@item.Title</title>
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<link>{0}</link>", item.Link.ToHtmlEncoded()))
    <description>@item.Description</description>
    <guid>@item.Guid</guid>
    @if (item.PublishedDateUtc.HasValue)
    {
    <pubDate>@item.PublishedDateUtc.Value.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") GMT</pubDate>
    }  
</item>      
}
```

Anyone have any better suggestions? Obviously, I could just use a class to declare model and return the XML directly from the controller, but I'm more interested in why this behavior occurs and what I can do to conform better to the Razor syntax.

Comment: Could you post the `</item>` tag the error message is talking about?

Comment: Updated the question with the tag and **a** workaround. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I first glanced at this I noticed your `link` tag had a closing tag instead of self closing. Razor is *smart* enough to know html and knows how the link tag is closed. Here is another example of something that could break to show how Razor reads html.

```
....
<tbody>
    @if (alternating) {
        <tr class='alternating'>
    } else {
        <tr>
    }

    ....

        </tr>
</tbody>
```

This will fail because it sees a `</tr>` without an opening tag.

Tags that are always self closing are interpreted by Razor to be self closing. so your `link` tag actually ended at the `>`. (since it's valid html to have a self closing tag without a `/>`) So now we come across a closing tag with no opening tag to justify it so the parser gives up and says that it's not properly formatted. I'd have to do some checking but I'm pretty sure it assumes the closing `link` tag was meant for the `item` tag since that would give proper balance which is why the rest of the file parses fine until it comes across this lone `item` tag with no opening tag.

It should be smart enough to know that the previous closing tag wasn't the right one. It might be an issue to take up with the team.

I haven't tried it but you should be able to do this

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
<item>
    <title>@item.Title</title>
    @:<link>
        @item.Link
    @:</link>
    <description>@item.Description</description>
    <guid>@item.Guid</guid>
    @if (item.PublishedDateUtc.HasValue)
    {
    <pubDate>@item.PublishedDateUtc.Value.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") GMT</pubDate>
    }  
</item>      
}
```

Comment: So, this is Razor trying to be to smart with HTML 5, since my example is an RSS feed in XML and not HTML 5. The **link** element is not a self closing element in this case.

Comment: This explains the behavior, but not a solution. (Not trying to be hard to get, but others will want to know what to do in this situation.) Is there a good solution to turning off Razor from conforming to the HTML 5 element syntax rules when compiling?

Comment: Understood, you stated `but I'm more interested in why this behavior occurs and what I can do to conform better to the Razor syntax.` which is what I was attempting to do :)

Comment: +1. I'll accept your answer on that basis. I'll go post a question to the MVC team and see if I can get a better overall solution.

Comment: I cross posted the [issue as a comment](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8878) on the MVC codeplex project.

Comment: Issue is now at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1529. Looks like they refuse to fix this bug, and a workaround is required.

Comment: This bug is still present, you'd think setting the ContentType would be enough. Ho hum.