# MVC 4 and Razor 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

We are currently upgrading an existing site from MVC 3 to MVC 4 and so far we have encountered these two issues with the razor views : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931376/asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-2-view-engine-no-longer-supports-xml) and 
[enter link description here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/390)

our main interest in MVC 4 is web api so razor takes a back seat, is there a way to configure MVC 4 to use Razor 1, my question is not to tackle a specific error configuring this but: is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to register the original Razor View Engine in the Global.asax.cs at startup... And remove the Razor 2 View Engine...

Comment: Also can customize it from the web. config within the views folder too I believe.